# sort the output with a column which is not included the view

Tags: sql

how do i sort my view with a column that is not there in the view itself! but present in the database?

Comment: You simply can't.

Comment: Add the column to the view or join the table to the view and sort the joined column.

Comment: What do YOU mean by "sort my view"?  Result sets are ordered when you use `ORDER BY`.  But not views or tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the result of a subquery:

```
select v.*
from view v
order by (select t.<whatver> from t where t.id = v.id);
```

Or you could use an explicit `join` to bring the column in.